# Limit of a sequence (Squeeze Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I came by a problem that I am not sure how to solve. My guess is that I have to use Squeeze theorem but I'm not able to figure out which known limits to use.
The problem is:

$$ \lim \limits_{n \to ∞} \frac{3^n}{(1+3) * (1+3^2) * ...* (1+3^n)}$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Upper bound was easy, for lower bound I took $$\frac{3^n}{3+3^n}$$ and its limit is 1 so I guess its right?

Comment: That easy upper bound is useless and your lower bound is false. Rather find some upper bound which tends to $0.$

Comment: Yeah i figured now that my lower bound is false, but can you explain  how is upper bound useless and do you have suggestion for lower bound?

Comment: Or notice $\frac{3^n}{(1+3)\cdot (1+3^2)\cdots (1+3^n)}=\frac{1}{(1+3)\cdot (1+3^2)\cdots (1+3^{n-1})}\cdot \frac{3^n}{1+3^n}$

Comment: Yeah I removed the comment because the upper bound was too loose. Thanks for pointing out @AnneBauval

Answer (score 1):

The denominator seems to grow much faster than the numerator. In particular, monic the polynomial $p_{n}(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots (1+x^n)$ has degree $1+2+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2>n$. Using this information, we have that $$\frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)\cdots (1+3^n)} < \frac{3^n}{3^{n(n+1)/2}} = \frac{1}{3^{n(n-1)/2}}.$$ This upper bound tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so you can do the rest here.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me

Comment: or just $\frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)\cdots (1+3^n)}=\frac{3}{1+3}\cdot\frac{3}{1+3^2}\cdots \frac{3}{1+3^n}\leq 1^{n-1}\cdot\frac{3}{1+3^n}$, which clearly vanishes as $n\to\infty$.